# what does this typescript interface mean?

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am learning angular5 and typescript, from angular.io website I saw an interface definition like below:

```js
export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
 canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
```

Just curious about the canDeactivate definition, whether it is data member of member function?
I know the last three types are union type, is it return type? why it follows an arrow (lambda expression?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed right. `Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;` is the return type of the function `canDeactivate` which take no arguments.

The `=>` is not a lambda expression, but TypeScript syntax to create a function return type.